# Relation between inverse Fourier transform of dyadic bump function and its regularity.

Tags: fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Let $\psi_k(|\xi|)$ be a bump function which support is $\{ \xi\in\mathbb{R^n}:2^{k} \le |\xi| \le 2^{k+1} \}$.

Then, for $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$, is this following equation (its inverse Fourier transform)
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} e^{ix\cdot \xi} \psi_k(|\xi|) \sqrt{1+|\xi|^{2}}^{\sigma} d\xi = C 2^{k\sigma} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} e^{ix\cdot \xi} \psi_k(|\xi|)d\xi$$

true for some $C$?

I tried an inequality of its  modulus version, $|(LHS)| \le C|(RHS)|$ by using Holder's inequality or Young's inequality. But, it was failed since the former removes $e^{ix\cdot\xi}$ and the latter removes pointwiseness of $x$ by taking $\| \cdot \|_{L^{\infty}}$ and it needs to calculate the Fourier inversion of $\sqrt{1+|\xi|^{2}}^{\sigma}$. More precisely, when I use Holder's,
$$ 
|(LHS)| \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} | e^{ix\cdot \xi} \psi_k(|\xi|)|d\xi\; \cdot \; \| \sqrt{1+|\xi|^{2}}^{\sigma}\|_{L^{\infty}(\text{supp}(\psi_k))}
$$
since $\psi_k$ is supported, or use Young's,
$$
|(LHS)| = | (\psi_{k})\check{} (x) \ast (\sqrt{1+|\cdot|^{2}}^{\sigma})\check{}(x)|
\le \| (\psi_{k})\check{}(x)\|_{L^{\infty}_{x}} \| (\sqrt{1+|\cdot|^{2}}^{\sigma})\check{}(x) \|_{L_x^{1}}.
$$

I think that it looks simple and obvious but I can't prove rigorously.

Comment: Are you trying to prove a bound or an equality? In any case (in $L^2$) if two Fourier transforms are equal the functions are equal. And you get a (functional) equation for $\psi_k$ which has no non-zero solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your comments exactly. But, yes, I want to prove the equality, at least $|(LHS)| \le |(RHS)|$, not solving that equation.

Comment: This is an *inequality* then, not an equality. I suppose what you want to prove is that there exists a constant $C>0$ independent of $k$ such that $|(LHS)| \leq C |(RHS)|$, right ? Because of course, in general, if $a = C\,b$, then it suffices to take $C = b/a$ ...

Comment: Since it have imaginary part (sine part) and it cannot decide order, I used the word 'equality' and I edited it. My main purpose is that equation is true for $=$. The reason why I mentioned inequality is because if I show $|(LHS)| \le C_1|(RHS)|$ and $|(LHS)| \ge C_2|(RHS)||$, it may prove equation $(LHS) = C(RHS)$  for some $C$, or we can say it is comparable its notation is $(LHS) \sim (RHS)$.

Comment: The equality cannot hold for all $x$, simply take the Fourier transform.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to know why you think something like this should hold.